# Working out truth table for Boolean equation

Tags: boolean

I am trying to work out the truth table for the Boolean Equation that I am badly explaining:

[A.B (NAND)] + [A+B (NOT NOR]

I would also be interested to know how I represent this equation properly using a standard character set. Help!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax in many programming languages is similar to the following

AND:

```
A && B
```

OR:

```
A || B
```

NOT:

```
!A
```

NAND:

```
!(A && B)
```

NOR:

```
!(A||B)
```

Hope that helps. If you have any questions don't hesitate to comment below!